# C programs in vim 7.3

Tags: vim, vi

At college we are writing some C code. I am used to vim 7.4, but I can't install it there because I don't have sudo privileges. I can't even save a vimrc on a computer because they delete all files after restart.

So my question is: how do you go about programming with these obstacles, do you carry your vimrc with you?

One more thing that bugs me is that 7.3 doesn't support cindent and filetype on; so I am left with only autoindent. My version output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 10 2013 06:43:40)
Included patches: 1-547
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic -autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms -byte_offset -cindent -clientserver -clipboard -cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist -cmdline_info -comments -conceal -cryptv -cscope -cursorbind -cursorshape -dialog -diff -digraphs -dnd
-ebcdic -emacs_tags -eval -ex_extra -extra_search -farsi -file_in_path -find_in_path -float -folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv -insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap -libcall -linebreak -lispindent -listcmds
-localmap -lua -menu -mksession -modify_fname -mouse -mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse -mouse_xterm -mouse_urxvt +multi_byte -multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -path_extra -perl -persistent_undo
-printer -profile -python -python3 -quickfix -reltime -rightleft -ruby -scrollbind -signs -smartindent -sniff -startuptime -statusline -sun_workshop -syntax -tag_binary -tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo -termresponse
-textobjects -title -toolbar -user_commands -vertsplit -virtualedit +visual -visualextra -viminfo -vreplace +wildignore -wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 +xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DTINY_VIMRC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo  -lselinux -lacl -lattr
```

So when I write code it tends to look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int whatever;
    return 0;
    }
```

Pressing c-d really feels like a waste of time. Anybody has any suggestions, maybe implementing some commands in the vimrc which I could carry around I guess?

Comment: I always carry USB memory in my pocket which has `.vimrc` in it. If you can connect to the network, how about sharing your `.vimrc` in github or something?.

Comment: 7.3 supports `cindent` and `fietype on`. Maybe your build doesn't? Can you update your question with the full output of `$ vim --version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That build is **totally** unfit for programming. Here are the most immediately obvious missing features:

```
-autocmd -cindent -clipboard -cmdline_compl -comments -cscope -diff
-eval -ex_extra -extra_search -file_in_path -find_in_path -float -folding
-gettext -insert_expand -modify_fname -lua -path_extra -perl -persistent_undo
-python -python3 -quickfix -reltime -ruby -signs -smartindent -statusline -syntax
-tag_binary -tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl -textobjects -user_commands
-vertsplit -virtualedit -visualextra -viminfo -vreplace -wildmenu
```

You have two options:

- build a proper Vim locally, all contained in a specific directory and copy that directory onto a USB stick so that you can put it back every day. Put your `~/.vim/` on that USB stick too for the same reason.
- explain to your professor/IT department/whatever that you can't really be expected to use that Vim for programming.

Comment: And when I come to class I put it in the home dir or in the vim dir?

Comment: Yes. See `$ ./configure --help` in Vim's source for all the options. You'll at least need `--prefix=/home/username/vim74` which should create all the necessary directories for you during `$ make` and `$make install`. Note that your machine may or may not have all the required dependencies so that solution may turn into an horrible timesink. Getting your IT to install a proper Vim is probably a better idea.